# Bit by unidentifiable spider

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

Live in South Florida and was outside cleaning and believe I got bit by this spider.

It is painful and need help identifying.

Comment: You need to provide a photo and an approximate size

Answer (score 1):

The only North American spider species of concern are the black widow (*Latrodectus mactans*) and brown recluse (*Loxosceles reclusa*). Unfortunately, these both occur in south Florida - but so do many other spiders.

I'm guessing the spider that bit you wasn't one of these two, for the following reasons:

- Black widows are widely identifiable by the general public, and you'd likely have recognized that by the highly characteristic red hourglass on black.
- Black widow bites hurt a lot. It takes an hour or so for the pain to really set in, but you'd know it was a serious problem.
- Brown recluse bites are rare, despite their wide range, and tend to happen indoors.

If you were bitten by anything else, the odds are incredibly high that the worst you'll deal with is a little red bump of irritation that goes away shortly.